# How do I fix this mesh faces issue? Tried recalculating normals and all

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces, normals

[image]

It happened earlier but I fixed it with flip normal, but now it's there again.

I have no idea what's causing it.

I'm a beginner, help me solve it. Thanks!